# realm objectsWhere doesn't work

Tags: ios, realm, nspredicate

I'm trying to fetch realm objects using NSPredicate.

This doesn't work

```
RLMResults *activtyResults = [[[self getActivitySource]activities] objectsWhere:@"ID ==[c] '%@'",activityID];
```

activtyResults is nil

This works:

```
for (RealmActivity *activity in [[self getActivitySource]activities]){
        if ([activity.ID isEqualToString:activityID]) {
            return activity;
        }
    }
```

The activityID is a uuid: f20f6217-9cb6-4fe1-9333-8956d1252112

Why the predicate format `@"ID ==[c] '%@'"` doesn't work here ?Does it have anything to do with the property name being ID ?

Answer (score 0):

A predicate of `ID == %@` would be equivalent to the imperative code you shared.

I'd expect the predicate you used to generate an error, rather than silently returning `nil`, due to the extraneous single quotes it contains. The lack of error combined with the `nil` result you're seeing suggests to me that the object you're invoking `-objectsWhere:` on is likely `nil`.